# Should I continue looking for jobs despite having signed a contract?

Tags: job-acceptance

I am a new graduate in engineering. I'm based in the UK and recently applied and was accepted to a job. I've signed the contract and the job begins in a month or two. However, I've been told to apply for multiple other jobs in case the offer is rescinded. My situation is that the job required a medical and I am concerned the company could rescind due to my disclosure of said medical condition.

I've been advised by relatives and others to keep looking and applying to see if I can do better/ as a backup, ideally outside of my field (elec engineering). I am concerned about the ethics of the thing, and I also feel I do not want to go through the whole job hunt, research, apply process again. Could someone please advise on my situation, it would be really appreciated?

Regards,

R

Comment: If, as you said, you signed a contract, how it comes that you don't know whether you start in a month or in two? There is a salary that you won't get.

Comment: If the company has had the results of the medical for a reasonable amount of time, it's entirely reasonable to contact them and say "I presume there were no problems on the tests, but I haven't heard from you about when and where I start. Could you give me that information, so I can start making appropriate plans?"

Answer (score 3):

You're concerned about the ethics of what "thing"? All the prospective employers'd be doing is invite you in for interviews. In return, all you're doing in showing for the interviews, introducing yourself to them and making the case as to why you should get an offer - There is no commitment from them to you and vice versa at this point.

Yes, an employer made you an offer and you signed a contract with them, but the relationship actually moving forward hinges on them not rescinding their offer to you.

Everybody's playing several games at once and looking out for themselves, and so should you.

Comment: Also worth noting even when employed it's not a bad idea to have a back up plan. Depending on your line of work some roles can be extremely volatile (not saying always interview, but never completely cut yourself off of having an eye out for other opportunities).

Answer (score 2):

This is really a matter of perspective. Your personal ethics probably tell you that keeping your prospects open in some way betrays your current employer. It doesn't. You should always keep all options open.  If you've accepted an offer, you're right, they can always rescind it, or circumstances with the company may change (like bankruptcy). I personally know of companies literally on the verge of bankruptcy, laying off employees, and hiring people in other divisions. It happens, protect yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You might re-frame the situation like this: Are you the only person capable of doing the job you applied for? In the majority of the cases **there are lots of people who can replace you**, so there is no major reason you should be bound to a particular company. Besides, **having people change jobs open possibilities for the company you signed the contract with as well as to the company which may offer you another job**, so let the chance play its role. Keep on looking for jobs, there exists an small possibility that you find something interesting, while you keep opened the door to start working in a month in the case your current offer doesn't get rescinded.

Answer (score 2):

I'm 66 years old, and CEO of a small company. The last few years we've done very well. I still couldn't go to sleep if I didn't have "Plan B" in my back pocket. Just looking doesn't mean you're moving, or in your case not taking the job. You surely shouldn't stop looking after one offer, especially when it's as tenuous as yours seems to be.

Keeping abreast of who's hiring and for how much elsewhere in the industry is an important thing to know, throughout your career.

Just graduated with an Engineering degree? You've got an exciting time ahead of you. Best of luck.

Comment: One thing to add to this, you should always have a plan B if for no other reason company / employee loyalty in these days is negligible in many companies. (though smaller ones tend to be better about it) Bottom line is employees and companies alike will follow the money... if it's more cost effective to cut you than keep you, you're gone. Just the same if you can make more money else where, you'll probably leave just as readily (assuming the roles are comparable)